# What's the difference between function_clause and badarg in Erlang?

Tags: exception, erlang

Sometimes I get `badarg` instead of `function_clause` but I cannot see the rule that would determine which one is going to appear.

As I understand, `function_clause` is thrown when no function's implementation matches given arguments. About `badarg` the documentation says

> The argument is of wrong data type, or is otherwise badly formed.

which seems to be covered by `function_clause` conditions...

For instance

```
lists:flatten(3).
```

throws clause error, while the type definitely does not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function clauses are parts of definition with different argument patterns/guards, as in

```
func({X, Y}) -> ...;
func(X) when X > 10 -> ...;
func(_) -> ...
```

`function_clause` means that none of them matched. There are similar `if_clause` and `case_clause`. For `flatten` with single argument there is [only one clause](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/0b9ff2f07dc1bc84325b5c3633efff719b2d20eb/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L616-L617)

```
flatten(List) when is_list(List) ->
    do_flatten(List, []).
```

which doesn't match `3`, which is why you get `function_clause`.

So

> Sometimes I get badarg instead of function_clause but I cannot see the rule that would determine which one is going to appear

This is basically an implementation detail which you should only care about when debugging the implementation of that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
1> F = fun({X,L}) ->  X + hd(L) end.                                                  
#Fun<erl_eval.7.91303403>
2> catch(F(5)). % 5 is not a tuple, so there is no clause in F definition which allow any evaluation 
{'EXIT',{function_clause,[{erl_eval,'-inside-an-interpreted-fun-',
                                    [5],
                                    []},
                          {erl_eval,eval_fun,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,829}]},
                          {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,437}]},
                          {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
                          {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,642}]},
                          {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,627}]}]}}
3> catch(F({5,6})). % in the tuple, 6 is not a list, it is a bad argument for erlang:hd/1
{'EXIT',{badarg,[{erlang,hd,[6],[]},
                 {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,684}]},
                 {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,480}]},
                 {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,437}]},
                 {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
                 {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,642}]},
                 {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,627}]}]}}
4> catch(F({5,[a]})). % now the error is detected in the addition you get a badarith
{'EXIT',{badarith,[{erlang,'+',[5,a],[]},
                   {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,684}]},
                   {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,437}]},
                   {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,686}]},
                   {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,642}]},
                   {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,627}]}]}}
5> catch(F({5,[6]})).
11
6>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the Official explanation:

#### badarg

Bad argument. The argument is of wrong data type, or is otherwise badly formed.

#### function_clause

No matching function clause is found when evaluating a function call.

---

sometimes badarg should be coverd by function_clause

but when do math operation, for example `1/0` will throw `badarg`

at most cases, when a function definition with a ***guard*** will throw `function_clause`